# Is the adjoint of an isometry an isometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, isometry

Consider a linear operator $V$ between two Hilbert spaces $H_A$ and $H_B$, we say that $V:H_A\rightarrow H_B$ is an isometry if $$ V^*V=\mathbb{1}_A$$

if 
$V$ is an isometry, does it always hold that $VV^*=\mathbb{1}_B$? 
In other words, is the adjoint on an isometry an isometry?
If not, does it in finite dimension? If not even in finite dimension, does anyone have a finite dimensional counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will hold in finite dimensional spaces if $\dim(H_A) = \dim(H_B)$.  It will not, however, hold more generally.

If we take $H_A = \Bbb C^2$ and $H_B = \Bbb C^3$, then the map
$$
V(x,y) = (x,y,0)
$$
is an isometry.  Its adjoint
$$
V^*(x,y,z) = (x,y)
$$
is not an isometry.

For an infinite dimensional example with $H_A = H_B$, we can take the [right shift operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Sequences) over $\ell^2$.

Comment: Thank you, math doesn't forgive I guess, does it hold in finite dimension that the restriction of $VV^*$ to a space of the same dimension of $H_A$ is the identity? It holds for the example you provided

Comment: @user438666 Yes, and you can say a bit more: $VV^*$ will always be the orthogonal projection onto the image of $V$ in $H_B$.